# Is there a way to execute a redis command on a key space notification?

Tags: redis

I am new to using Redis and have been tinkering around with it to get a better idea of how it all works. I have a queue called `available_workers:queue` of values (`workers`) where the queue itself represents the overall state of `available_workers`. As I pop a value (`worker`) from the queue and use it, two things can happen:

1. The state of the `worker` *does not* change and is pushed back into the `available_workers:queue`.
2. The state of the `worker` *does* change (it becomes exhausted for a period of time) and a new key is created `{id}:worker` with a command such as `SET 132303:worker worker_value EX 100`

Is it possible to on expiration of the key `132303:worker` to trigger a Redis command to `push` the value *back* to the `available_workers:queue`? I have read the official [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/) but don't see what I am looking for... Is this even possible to do using something like Redis? Or will I need to create some service in code to manage this? Thanks in advance to all of those who reply!

Comment: You might want to check the RedisGears modules for Redis see: https://oss.redis.com/redisgears

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own notifications just by calling PUBLISH alongside the calls that modify the data - for atomicity consider using transactions or a Lua script

```
PUBLISH __keyspace@0__:mykey del
PUBLISH __keyevent@0__:del mykey
```